# Lists of arrays

Tags: python, arrays, list, numpy

```
[array([
        [[ 885, 2876]],
        [[ 880, 2881]],
        [[ 880, 2882]],
        [[ number1, number2]]
       ]
 ),
 array([
        [[2287, 2753]],
        [[2285, 2755]]
       ]
 ),
 array([
        [[2323, 2534]],
        [[2320, 2537]],
        [[number3, number4]]
        [[number5, number6]]
       ]
 )
]
```

I want to append these numbers (number1, number2, ...)to my list of arrays in order to have my original list with those values.

My problem is that when I use np.append(list[0] ,[[[number1,number2]]] , axis=0) what I get it is not my original list with that values it is just the array in the position 0 of my list of arrays with the values appended.

However i want the whole list with number1 and number2 appended in list[0] and so on.

Comment: `np.vstack(xxx).reshape(xxx)`

Comment: No, I printed the whole list and it is not append any value in it

Comment: xxx means each number? number1, number2

Comment: post the expected output too.

Comment: `np.append` does not operate in-place.  Please review its docs and test some simpler cases.  Look at its code.  Review `np.concatenate`.

Comment: the expected output its alrredy there. It is the list of arrays with the values number1, number2 ... in the arrays

Comment: is it so that you list[0] want to append one new row with the numbers coming from elsewhere, then nothing to list[1] and finally 2 rows to list[2]?
if so, what is deciding what you want to append and where? anyways, if this is your question do a for loop with a zip(rows_to_append, the_list) and use `np.vstack` in the loop. If a is a 2x2 matrix, `np.vstack((a,a))` becomes a 4x2 matrix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a straight forward array concatenation task, provided you take care with the number of dimensions.  And remember, concatenation (with all the stack and append variants) is not in-place.

Your list:

In [352]: alist
Out[352]: 
[array([[[ 885, 2876]],

```
    [[ 880, 2881]],

    [[ 880, 2882]]]), array([[[2287, 2753]],

    [[2285, 2755]]]), array([[[2323, 2534]],

    [[2320, 2537]]])]
```

The arrays are 3d:

```
In [353]: alist[0].shape
Out[353]: (3, 1, 2)
```

Add `[number1, number2]` to the first list item; I had to add a couple of layers of [] so its dimensions match: (1,1,2)

```
In [354]: alist[0] = np.concatenate((alist[0],np.array([[[1,2]]])),axis=0)
```

The result is a (4,1,2) array.  Similarly for the third array.

```
In [355]: alist[2] = np.concatenate((alist[2],np.array([[[3,4]],[[5,6]]])),axis=0)

In [350]: alist
```

In [356]: alist
Out[356]: 
[array([[[ 885, 2876]],

```
    [[ 880, 2881]],

    [[ 880, 2882]],

    [[   1,    2]]]), array([[[2287, 2753]],

    [[2285, 2755]]]), array([[[2323, 2534]],

    [[2320, 2537]],

    [[   3,    4]],

    [[   5,    6]]])]
```